# How do I clean up the mess after an installation aborts?

Tags: software-installation, cleanup

I'm sure it's happened to everyone some time....

I was installing something with Ubuntu Software Center, a lot downloaded, but it crapped out half way through the installation with errors to the effect of the app is out of date and missing parts.

For one thing, I don't know where apps download to when using USC, when I download things, I put them in their own folder.

Is there an app to clean up fragments? Terminal commands?

Comment: It's always helpful to all concerned if you post the exact terminal output or a screenshot rather than trying to paraphrase what you saw.

Answer (score 0):

Good advise above.  USC is best noted for showing possible matches to needs in categories or by partial names or term matches.  For instance, you can type in py or python and find out lots.  Or tex, text, edit, editor, or combine tex ed and get a host of possible matches.  You even have a star rating system, whether it is already installed or not, and under More, a brief breakdown on what it is or does,  And if you download a deb file from someplace, USC will seek to install it for you.  But under some conditions, USC craps out or gets hung, forcing st least a logout to get it to close.

So you have aLternatives, like apt-get, aptitude, and synaptic.  Only apt and apt-get, and USC come as part of the Ubuntu install as far as I know.  The other two can of course be installed.  Synaptic rivals USC in giving you choice, but is not quite as generous with details and user ratings.

Apt adds more functionality to apt-get and apt-cache  it allows searches, show,list, and install as options.  The search finds pattern matches like as you get in USC and synaptic, but from the command like.  Since you can have multiple reeminals in separate windows, with copy-and-paste, you can take the colored name in the search window and do a show in another window or a list in a third,  you can even do an install ina forth window,

Unfortunately, in the latest 14.04 release, apt reports it does not have a stable CLI (command line interface) and cannot work properly with any pipe symbols like >,>>, or |.  Under test, this proved to be an understatement.  It tanked in each case.  I will miss this feature until it returns,  Meanwhile usc is doing its job.  The thing about USC is that you can queue more installs and removes while one is in progress before uour sudo rights time out.

It can be a bit difficult to maneuver up and down the possible candidates list.  It sort of jams when you near the top going up, or near the bottom scrolling sown.  A part of the problem could be a hyoersensative rouchpad on my laptop.  What haooens most often is the focus on the list got dropped even though one of the list items appears to be still selected.  Try selecting it or a different entry again with the mouse and use the up or down arrow key to continue your journey up or down the list.

Loaded packages generally show up in Dash or the main menu selections if using a Gnome-session-Manager alternative like Metacity.  I like Metacity as it gives me a lot of direct control over directories or files; at least at the user account level.

Comment: Here's my process, I find something I want to install, maybe in the USC, maybe on another website. If it's in the USC, I "read more" and look at the reviews. I guess now if there are no reviews for over a year, the app probably is not being maintained, so don't use it . THen I go searching elsewhere. If I get lucky, there's a few lines to copy/paste into the terminal, and most of the time that works. Then there's the "download" button with no instructions. Sometimes I can download it and double click and it installs, sometimes not.  I only got 14.04 a week ago. First linux OS I ever used.